# Latitude in raster calc operation

Tags: r, coordinates, r-raster

I'm trying to create a Koppen world map using data from http://worldclim.org. To find the right Koppen climate I need precipitation and temperature data (I have one raster map for each month for each of those two variables) and the latitude.

I tried doing the following :

```
prast <- list.files(path = "prec25/", pattern = glob2rx('*.tif'), full.names = T)
trast <- list.files(path = "temp25/", pattern = glob2rx('*.tif'), full.names = T)
lrast <- c(prast, trast)
climrast <- stack(lrast)

koppen_map <- calc(climrast, filename = "koppen.tif", fun = function(x) koppen(x[13:24], x[1:12], yFromCell(climrast, x[1])))
```

`climrast` is a RasterStack with the 24 different layers (12 layers with temperature data and 12 layers with precipitation data). The `koppen` function needs a vector with 12 values for temperature (that would be `x[13:24]`) and 12 values for temperature (`x[1:12]`).

`yFromCell(climrast, x[1])` should give me the latitude but the `calc` operation fails because `yFromCell(climrast, x[1])` returns `NA` in some cases.

If I replace the `yFromCell(climrast, x[1])` with an arbitrary number like 10, the calc operation works fine.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The memory-safe (and simple) way to get a RasterLayer with latitude values, you can do:

```
x <- init(climrast, 'y')
```

A working example with worldclim data:

```
library(raster)
prast <- getData('worldclim', var='prec', res=10)
tmin <- getData('worldclim', var='tmin', res=10)
tmax <- getData('worldclim', var='tmin', res=10)
trast <- (tmin + tmax) / 2

lat <- init(trast, 'y')

lrast <- stack(prast, trast, lat)
climrast <- crop(lrast, extent(25,30,-5,0))

# example function
koppen <- function(temp, prec, lat) {
    (sum(temp * prec) + lat) / 1000
}

koppen_map <- calc(climrast, filename = "koppen.tif", fun = function(x) koppen(x[13:24], x[1:12], x[25]), overwrite=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `calc` you are passing `x[1]` to `yFromCell`.  But `x[1]` is the value of the raster cell, whereas you need to pass the cell number to `yFromCell`.  I can illustrate with a minimal example:

First lets make a small dummy raster

```
library(raster)
set.seed(0)
clim = raster(matrix(sample(c(1:10,NA), 100, T), 10, 10))
```

Now lets try to get its latitudes using an analogy of what you had in the example

```
lat = calc(clim, function(x) yFromCell(clim, x))
plot(lat)
```

[image]

As you can see, that's not right at all - we got entirely the wrong latitude values because we passed the cell value rather than the cell number.

So lets make a raster layer that has the correct latitudes

```
lat = clim
lat[] = yFromCell(clim, 1:ncell(clim))
plot(lat)
```

[image]

That's much better.  Now we can add this as a layer to our climate data, so that `calc` can access these values on a cell by cell basis.

```
climrast = stack(list(clim, lat))
koppen = calc(climrast, function(x) x[1]*x[2])
```

Comment: Thank you for this quite detailed answer! It was very helpful.

I do however have an issue when working with higher resolution rasters:
`Error : vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
Error in .local(x, values, ...) : values must be a vector or a matrix`

Couldn't I access the cell number in the calc function?